# Finding set of possible values of a constant in a function definition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It is given that the function

$f(x) = \sqrt{(mx + 7)} - 4$

$x \geq -\frac{7}{m}$

and its inverse do not intersect, and that neither intersect the line $y = x$.

How could one determine the set of possible values for the positive constant m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you talk of $y$, presumably you mean $f(x)$.  Since $f$ is continuous, to avoid having you must either have $f(x)\gt x$ for all $x$ or have $f(x) \lt x$ for all $x$.  This explicitly keeps $f(x)$ from meeting $y=x$.  You can set $f(x)=x$ and find what values of $m$ make it impossible to satisfy.  The condition that $f(x) \ne f^{-1}(x)$ is covered as you must have $f(x)\gt x \gt f^{-1}(x)$ or the reverse.

Comment: Yes, y is specified as being equal to f(x). My teachers over the years have generally used 'y' and 'f(x)' interchangeably.

Comment: The only appearance of $y$ in the post is in *the line $y=x$*, which looks correct to me. (On the other hand, to say that *$f$ and $f^{-1}$ meet* to mean that the graphs of the functions $f$ and $f^{-1}$ intersect, is questionable. Likewise for the graph of $f$ and the line $y=x$.)